# get next Row when importing file CSV with grails

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, csv, groovy

i am trying to import file CSV like this image..

this image means..

when i import this file..line 1 with read and save in to Table SeniorHighSchool
then it will get :

1. name : Alexander
2. age  : 15
3. muchcourse : 3

after that i want make a condition, When "muchcourse is filled" it will read the next row...
example :
at this case, the "muchcourse" is "3", then "look at the image"..row 2,3,4 (3 lines)will inserted to other table .. because the "muchcourse" is "3"

[image]

this is my coding what i have tried .

```
def upload = {
            withForm{
                def f = request.getFile('filecsv')
                def orifilename = f.getOriginalFilename()
                def homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")) 
                def homeurl = "Documents/Uploads/"
                File fileDest = new File(homeDir,homeurl+orifilename)
                f.transferTo(fileDest)  

                request.getFile(new File(fileDest)).InputStream.splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
                def student= new SeniorHighSchool(
                    name: fields[0].trim(),
                    age: fields[1].trim(),
                    muchcourse: fields[2].trim()

                    )
                if (student.hasErrors() || student.save(flush: true) == null)
                {
                    log.error("Could not import domainObject  ${student.errors}")
                }
                }

                redirect(action:"list")

            }
                }
```

i confused to make a condition..

```
  def upload = {
                    withForm{
                        def f = request.getFile('filecsv')
                        def orifilename = f.getOriginalFilename()
                        def homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")) 
                        def homeurl = "Documents/Uploads/"
                        File fileDest = new File(homeDir,homeurl+orifilename)
                        f.transferTo(fileDest)  

                        request.getFile(new File(fileDest)).InputStream.splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
                        def student= new SeniorHighSchool(
                            name: fields[0].trim(),
                            age: fields[1].trim(),
                            muchcourse: fields[2].trim()

                            )
                        if (student.hasErrors() || student.save(flush: true) == null)
                        {
                            log.error("Could not import domainObject  ${student.errors}")
                        }

                       if(fields[2]) {
                       def score = new Score(
                       course: //the problem at this line..how?
                               //it will insert 3 times then back to the row 5 to insert into "Student" again
                        )



    }
                        }

                        redirect(action:"list")

                    }


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(fields.size()>2){
  store 3 values in one table(student)
}
else{
  store 2 values in another table(score)
}
```

If muchcourse field is occured then fields size is 3 then save three data in one table. otherwise size is 2 then save that two data in another table.I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: If you are trying to associate the courses to the student, then you'll probably need to store a reference to student above the scope of your iterator as well so that you can associate the courses to the student that is currently being processed. Next time you see a student line, store that as the current student.

Comment: If student is associate with course, then we can do like the following.def student,course;in if part, student = one table and save;else part create course then add it to student and save student

Answer (score 0):

@th3morg like thiss?

```
request.getFile(new File(fileDest)).InputStream.splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
if(fields.size()>2){
  def student= new SeniorHighSchool(
                    name: fields[0].trim(),
                    age: fields[1].trim(),
                    muchcourse: fields[2].trim()
                    )
}
else{
  def score = new Score(
  course:fields[0].trim(),
  score:fields[1].trim()  
  )
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class SeniorHighStudent "static hasMany = [scores: Score]" then the following should do the trick:

```
    def currentStudent
    request.getFile(new File(fileDest)).InputStream.splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
        if(fields.size()>2){
            if(currentStudent){
                /*we've found a new student, so save the previous one*/
                currentStudent.save()
            }
            currentStudent = new SeniorHighSchool(
                    name: fields[0].trim(),
                    age: fields[1].trim(),
                    muchcourse: fields[2].trim()
            )
        }
        else{
            /*add the score to the currentStudent's scores*/
            currentStudent.addToScores(new Score(
                    course:fields[0].trim(),
                    score:fields[1].trim()
            ))
        }
    }
    /*when the loop is done, save the last student because it hasn't been saved yet*/
    currentStudent.save()
```